# Chat FAQ text is unreadable with the beta theme

Tags: bug, chat, design

The text says

> Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the [faq](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

I think it needs to have its color changed, because I need to highlight the text or squint up close to read it.

[image]

Image as seen on the [♦ Chat Relay - PPCG Minecraft Server](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26380/chat-relay-ppcg-minecraft-server)

Comment: I know devs view per-site metas sometimes but I think it would've been better for mother meta

Comment: @mbomb007 I migrated it to Meta.SE.

Comment: @Downgoat fwiw, SE has an internal bug tracking system that tracks the relevant tags (eg. 'bug') across all metas

Comment: @Adam Uhh you still need to fix it, duplicate or not... It's a simple fix too.